# Looking for batch automation program to reorganize/move/sort files into a new folder/directory structure based on file name content  (Windows)

Tags: windows, file-management

I have music files that already have artist name and title in the file name. However the files are currently not well organised in folders.

I don't require audio-fingerprinting.

Is there a program that can reorganise the files based on the contents of the file name (e.g. "Artist - Title.mp3" or "Artist - Album - Title.mp3")?

I could write a Perl script but would rather see what tools might be available already.

I would like them organised in folders as follows

- Alphabetically by Artist first initial letter

  - Artist name

    - Album/EP Title

      - track.mp3
      - track.mp3

    etc

My research so far on SuperUser (not quite found what I'm looking for):

- [Windows 7, any way to sort folders and files all mixed together?](https://superuser.com/questions/329127/windows-7-any-way-to-sort-folders-and-files-all-mixed-together) - this is just adjusting the *view* of the files in Explorer, not actually *where* they reside
- [Is there software that will organize files and folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/270865/is-there-software-that-will-organize-files-and-folders) - talks more about categories - not quite the same as what I need
- [Best way to organize lots and lots of media files?](https://superuser.com/questions/39822/best-way-to-organize-lots-and-lots-of-media-files) - Solution is to just search. Not what I would prefer. I don't plan to add to what I have - it will be an archive so the need to keep re-organising won't be there, it will be a one-off, so to reorganize is worthwhile.

Possible tools that *might* do the job (please advise):

- [Total Commander ( from ghisler.com )](http://www.ghisler.com/)
- [DriveSort - ( from anerty.net )](http://www.anerty.net/software/file/DriveSort/) - looks a bit old though
- [Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc) - But looks more like a clean-up tool than a general purpose re-organiser
- [Peter's Flexible Renaming Kit (PFrank)](http://www3.telus.net/pfrank/) - The most flexible Windows-based batch file *renamer* available. I may be able to use just the folder creation part.

Comment: Are the MP3 tags correct or do you only have the filename as indicator?

Comment: I don't know @Feroc. File names correctly stated should be enough though (?)

Comment: For the way you want to use it, yes. If the tags would be correct, too, there would be alternative tools to organize a mp3 collection.

Comment: @Feroc thanks, yes, I like MP3TAG - can it do it? Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Well, if the tags are correct you could also use iTunes and let iTunes take over the sorting of files. Per default it sorts it exactly the way you described: [Artist]/[Album]. Guess other media libraries (like Media Monkey) could sort it, too.

Comment: +1 @Feroc, for the iTunes suggestion. But at the moment I'm not a fan of iTunes generally 1) because it seems sluggish and 2) is not transparent in some things that it does. But +1 for the input; it's good to have options.

Comment: I am not going to defend iTunes. It's a pretty annoying tool, but it sorts pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in PFrank - pointer to solution here: http://pfrank.s4.bizhat.com/pfrank-ftopic277.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used [MP3/Tag Studio](http://www.magnusbrading.com/mp3ts/).

It does all of the above and more, a very powerful tool for sorting MP3s. There was an old utility for the Nomad Jukebox called MP3 Library that also had many tools and alowed you to edit fields like entries in Excel.